Fermions can be described by both symmetric and antisymmetric wavefunctions?
I stumbled upon a lecture note on MIT OpenCourseWare, as I was trying to read up on antisymmetric and symmetric wavefunctions of two particle Fermions and Bosons, respectively.
Interestingly, I came across a sentence that said the following:

... fermions can be described by both symmetric wave functions (with a
complicated many­particle Hamiltonian)or antisymmetric wave functions
(with a simpler many­particle Hamiltonian).I personally believe that
symmetric wave functions plus complicated many­particle Hamiltonian is
a correct way to understand fermions, at least physically. The
standard understanding using antisymmetric wave function is very
formal and misleading despite its mathematical simplicity.

Instead of trying to arrive at Fermi and Bose statistics through the imposition of symmetrization and antisymmetrization of the total wavefunction, the note says the following:

In contrast, the description of identical particle using symmetric
wave function and encoding the statistics in the many­particle
Hamiltonian leads to completely different picture. I believe it is a
more correct picture that captures more essence of statistics despite
its mathematical complexity. Within such a picture, statistics of
identical particles is a dynamical property determined by manyparticle
Hamiltonian. We can change the Hamiltonian to obtain different
statistics. We can also naturally obtain fractional statistics in two
dimensions. Such an understanding tells us how to make different
statistics. We can also have phase transitions that change the
statistics of particles. We will have a more detailed discussion of
Fermi statistics later.

I have never seen such treatment of Bosonic and Fermionic wavefunctions given in the lecture note (and I frankly don't understand the Hamiltonian used to prove the point of both Fermions and Bosons being described in symmetrized form).
I have two questions:

The note says with the more complicated Hamiltonian, you can start with both Fermions and Bosons having symmetric wavefunctions but arrive at Fermi and Bose statistics, respectively. Is Fermi and Bose statistics the only things we need to worry about as an implication of symmetric, and antisymmetric nature of particle wavefunctions?

Are there other references I can refer to to better understand this idea? The idea of having both Fermionic and Bosonic particles having symmetrized wavefunctions.



I've never seen this before and I have no references for you, but I think I can explain it.
One dimension
Usually one thinks of a fermionic wave function as being zero where the coordinates of two particles are equal, but you could also take the view that it just isn't defined there; you don't lose any information by doing so. In 1D, that has the effect of disconnecting the wave function into $n!$ open pieces: if $n=3$, they're the one where $x_1<x_2<x_3$, the one where $x_1<x_3<x_2$, etc. They are copies of each other and evolve identically. You can give them arbitrary relative phases without changing anything. Conventionally, the ones corresponding to odd permutations are 180° out of phase with the others, but you can just as well let them all be in phase.
Two dimensions
In two or more dimensions, dropping the coordinates excluded by the Exclusion Principle doesn't disconnect the wave function. You can swap two particles by continuous motion without passing them through each other, and this must introduce a factor of $-1$ relative to not swapping them over the same span of time. The complicated two-fermion Hamiltonian in these notes looks like it's cooked up so that rotating the line segment connecting the two particles by $θ$ also introduces a phase of $θ$ in the time evolution, which satisfies the swapping requirement. It doesn't matter that swapping the labels ($1\leftrightarrow 2$) doesn't introduce a factor of $-1$, because it's just a change of coordinates with no bearing on the outcome of any experiment.
This approach to 2D fermions has the advantage that you can change the $θ$ phase to $2sθ$ for any $s\in\mathbb R$ to get anyonic statistics.
Three dimensions
The notes don't seem to talk about a generalization to 3 or more dimensions, and it's not clear to me that the idea does generalize. The problem is that you seem to need a continuous function from 3D angles to phases ($S^2\to S^1$) with the property that antipodal points of the domain map to antipodal points of the range, and I think that no such function exists. (The image of half of the equator must loop around $S^1$ a half-integer number of times, so the image of the equator must loop around an odd number of times; now shrink that to a point at a pole, whose image loops 0 times. Continuity must break somewhere.)
But it occurs to me that it might be possible to finesse this somehow with particles of nonzero spin, since you have in that case not just the line segment representing relative position but also the orientation of the spins relative to that line to work with. It would be especially nice if it only worked for half-integer spin, since that would suggest a connection to the spin-statistics theorem. And I think that may actually be the case: the angle between each particle's spin axis and the line segment between them will rotate by 180° when you exchange the particles, and combining the two might get you a rotation of 360°. But I'm not seeing how exactly to do it, or how to show it can't be done with spin 1.
